# quit function does not work in try-except block

Tags: python, function, try-except

this is quit function that ı want to run it in the try except block..

```
def quit_function(quit):
     if(quit=="quit"):
        sys.exit(1)
```

when I enter correct input it works function_one but when I write "exit" in order to exit the program quit_function doesn't work, the except part works so output is "invalid input"..how can I fix it?

```
 while True:
    try:
        a=raw_input("Enter input :").lower()
        function_one(a)
        quit_function(a)
    except:
        print "invalid input"
    else:
        break
```

Comment: And this, future readers, is why you ***never ever ever ever*** write bare `except` clauses.

Comment: ***NEVER*** use a bare `except:`. *Always* specify the type of the exception: `except ValueError:` or `except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError):`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit` raises a [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit), which inherits from `BaseException`.

You are catching the exit in your `except` block. Try making the `except` more specific, to only catch normal exceptions (not exit signals):

```
try:
   ...
except Exception:
   print "Invalid input"
```

Better yet, figure out the actual specific type of exception you need to catch and only catch that.

Answer (score 0):

The `sys.exit` function actually raises a special `SystemExit` exception, which will propogate up the stack, executing `finally` blocks of try statements as it goes, until the exception gets caught or reaches the top of the stack. In the latter case, python cleanly exits, rather than printing a traceback. To avoid catching the `SystemExit` exception, change your bare `except` statement to `except Exception` or something more specific. Or, **if you really need to exit immediately without excpetion handlers running**, you can use `os._exit`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume *when I write "exit"* actually meant *when I write "quit"* since your function looks for the string `"quit"`.

First since you have a generic `except` block, you aren't seeing what the actual `Exception` is so I am going to bet that `function_one("quit")` throws an `Exception`. You need to process `quit_function()` before `function_one()`.

Second, `sys.exit()` also throws a specialized type of exception so `except:` isn't going to cut it.

Something along these lines should work:

```
while True:
    try:
        a=raw_input("Enter input :").lower()
        quit_function(a)
        function_one(a)
    except Exception:
        print "invalid input"
    else:
        break
```